# When scraping website with requests I cant search specific things

Tags: python

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ts = time.time()

friend_api_url = 'https://api.namemc.com/profile/' # + /friends
player = 'https://namemc.com/profile/surfboarding'
username_to_uuid = 'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/' # + username + ?at=(timestamp)

def findFriendByUsername(player, target): #add a function to find a users friend my username (player) is the player you want to search the friends of
    r = requests.get(username_to_uuid + player + '?at=' + str(ts)) #uses mojangs api scrapes website (there uuid is the "id" part) (ts is the timestamp)
    uuid_get = r.json()
    uuid = (uuid_get['id']) # gets uuid
    friend_scrape = requests.get(friend_api_url + uuid + '/friends')
    response = friend_scrape.json()
    names = [] #all usernames (dont know how to explain it)
    for names in response: #makes loop to print usernames
        player_friends = print(names['name']) #prints username
        #returns output of the friends usernames
        if player_friends==(target):
            print('The username ' + (target) + ' is in ' + player + ' friends list') #concatinates usernames into one string
```

Currently Im trying to scrape a websites api and I search everything with the name (name) which fetches the username for who im trying to search It brings many strings of characters and Im trying to make a program where I can search it so I try to use if player_friends==(target): But it seems like I never get a output saying that they found that username it seems like its just one big clump of letters, Is there anyway I can make this searchable (sorry if the formatting is bad im pretty knew to stackoverflow)

Comment: Try to avoid use the same variable name. You have a global variable `player` but your function also has parameter named `player`. Also the for loop has same var name `names`.

Comment: oh yea thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```py
import mcuuidButWorks.api as mcuuid
import requests

def areFriends(player1: str, player2: str) -> bool:
    friends: list = []
    api: str = "https://api.namemc.com/profile/"
    player = mcuuid.GetPlayerData(player1)
    uuid = player.uuid
    api = api + uuid + "/friends"
    response = requests.get(api).json()
    for player in response:
        friends.append(player["name"])
    return True if player2 in friends else False
```

With this, you could do something like:

```py
if areFriends("player1", "player2"):
    . . .
```

like you mentioned.